# Python - Replace outliers with max in the group

Tags: python, pandas

Can you please help with this coding part?

I need to replace the outlier values by grouping, in this data frame in Python:

```py
df = pd.DataFrame(['A', 'A',    'A',    'A',    'A',    'A',    'A',    'B',    'B',    'B',    'B',    'B',    'B',    'B',    'B',    'B'], columns = ['Key'])
df['Value'] = [22,  10, -100,   34, 780,    34, 29, 89, 53, 85, 77, 2,  90, 1,  298,    65]
```

I need to first group by Key column and then detect outliers using code similar to the below:

```py
    def is_outlier(s):
        lower_limit = s.mean() - (s.std() * 4.7)
        upper_limit = s.mean() + (s.std() * 4.7)
        return ~s.between(lower_limit, upper_limit)
```

Once the records are identified, I need to replace the high outlier value with the second max value (or median * 2?) and the low outlier value with the second lowest value.

There could be multiple outliers in the same group as in the example.

Thank you for the help!

Comment: Could you add your DataFrame in a way it can be copied in a text-editor

Comment: Can you create [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) ? Because if apply your function to your sample data, returned are all False.

Comment: [Please don't post images of code/data (or links to them)](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question)

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. I updated the post to include the data frame setup